# Changing States with AngularJS using element from an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5-canvas

I have an array filled with articles, showing one element:

```
$scope.articles = [];

//New article
var article = {};
article.heading = "A DISCUSSION WITH ATHEISTS ON EVOLUTION";
article.date = "December 24, 2017";
article.description = "The point of my discussion was to attempt to convince a relatively large group of atheists in r/DebateAnAtheist that the theory of evolution which they hold on to so dearly is in fact a random process. It is generally maintained that evolution is not random due to natural selection. This idea, however, is fundamentally flawed.";
article.link = "evolution-debate";
article.img = "templates/articles/evolution-debate/darwin.jpg";
//Add to array
$scope.articles.push(article);
```

I want to change my state to the evolution-debate state:

```
.state("evolution-debate", {
        url: "/evolution-debate",
        templateUrl: "templates/articles/evolution-debate.html",
        controller: 'articles'
    })
```

But since I load my articles from the array, I need to change the state using the article.link property from my array object.

I am currently using this code, but it won't change the state:

```
<ul class="actions">
     <li><a ng-click="go('{{article.link}}')" class="button big">READ NOW</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use <a ui-sref="{{article.link}}">READ NOW</a> to navigate to your article

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Also adding as an answer in case someone has a similar issue, it is easier to follow answers than comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ui-sref to navigate to your articles

```
<a ui-sref="{{article.link}}">READ NOW</a>
```